# Extension of ideals to powers series rings: example of $IR[[x]]\ne I[[x]]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

It is not hard to show that if $I$ is a finitely generated ideal of a ring $R$ (here we assume $R$ contains identity and commutative), then $IR[[x]]$ is the ideal of all power series having their coefficients in $I$.

However, I am curious about the counter-example when $I$ is not finitely generated. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be any ideal and suppose that $IR[[x]] = I[[x]]$. Then fix any countable subset $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty} \subset I$. Let $F = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} a_i x^i \in I[[x]]$. By assumption we can find finitely many $b_j \in I$ and $G_j \in R[[x]]$ such that $F = \sum b_j G_j$. Consequently the ideal generated by the $a_i$ is contained in the finitely generated ideal generated by the $b_j$.

In particular if $I$ is countably generated then the property  $IR[[x]] = I[[x]]$ implies that $I$ is finitely generated.

This suggests lots of simple counterexamples. Fix any ring $A$, and set $R = A[x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots]$. The ideal $I$ generated by the $x_i$ does not have the property above, because it is countably generated by the $x_i$ but is not finitely generated.